# Database project in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I write social media application and I am new in noSQL databases.
I would like to ask about some advice and opinion about my database project.

@Updated image
[image]

Also I want to do one more table for notification (when someone comment, like our post/comment and when someone accept our invitation to friends). I thought about make 3 different tabels - notification_post, notification_comment, notification_friend_accept, but I don't if this is good idea...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your database is prety relational, this is a strong indicator to use a relational database, but let's go!

When we design noSQL databases, like MongoDB, we need to avoid normalization, or "over normalization". This means that is more interesting repeat than avoid duplications.

There is some **design patterns** to MongoDB, and maybe the easiest one is **Extended Reference**. You'll find this useful when a lot of joins are needed to retrieve data. This design pattern tells to duplicate the most frequent data. Another one is **subset**, this will probably help.

Every time you bring a post, probably you'll show the comments number, some comments, likes number and so on. With this in mind, you can put your likes objects inside comments and posts, removing the collection. This avoid a second lookup on another collection. Probably remove the **last_like** property and sort the "likes array" descending by date and pull the first one.

Remember, documents in MongoDB are atomic, they are full loaded on RAM before any filtering.

Comment: I thought about this project, and in my opinion I can't avoid normalization, because what if someone change for example his avatar, name or surname ? I would have to change it in every post, comment etc. So I think that I have to use id as 'reference'. I change this project and updated. What do you think now ?

Comment: No, the post/comment don't need to contain all the user again, only an _id referencing the registry is fine. Looks better for post and comments, but there is a possbility to have millions os likes? This will bloat the document (but I don't think that this number will appear). There is a observation about the chat collection, you'll probably have much messages with a considerable size, making every query on chat a heavy one, specifically this one I think is better split in two collections. And, please, remember, this is only my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can do it that way, but keep in mind you are going to have to do 3x queries. Perhaps a generic `Notification{ notifcationTypeEnum: 'abc', ...}` would be more appropriate.